# Is there a decent open source map-editor?

Tags: open-source-gis, map-editor, map-drawing

I would like to have an open source map editor for drawing a city map? I don't want to use [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org). It will be a custom map project.

I don't need an advanced GIS system, but a simple map-editor, where I can use my own custom symbols. It must support Transverse Mercator projection and be able to calculated distances between objects on the map.

Comment: this should be merged with http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10071/open-source-map-composing-tool. Even though this question is older, the newer version has better answers. (In my opinion this shows the our community is growing, getting better through time, yay!).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Depends on your needs.

QGIS, gvSIG, etc, are all good map editors. Just download OSM data and use these to create your maps.

Also, you might consider creating your map with one those above, and then go to something like InkScape to finish the job.

Comment: qgis is a good starting point for a project like this.

Comment: +1 for QGIS, the editing tools work pretty nicely in the newer versions.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest too to use a traditional GIS software to extract and transform the data, and then to work on another software to work on the cartography. There are import/export procedures in almost all softwares to transfer your data.

[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) and also [OCAD](http://www.ocad.com/) are good software for cartography.

Comment: +1 for Inkscape.  I don't make maps very often, but I've finished maps in Inkscape after starting them in ArcMap on more than one occasion.

Answer (score 2):

I have had good success using [Viking](http://viking.sf.net), a free/open source program to manage GPS data, for doing some mapping applications, especially where I have had to composite different sources.