# Open Source Map Composing Tool

Tags: open-source-gis, tools, gui

Are there any open source tools which can be used for map composing, preferably GUI based. I use Quantum GIS sparingly but I am interested to know if there are others. The tool must be able to read raster/vector layers in standard formats and allow exporting in various formats. Something like GeoPDF export would be a great plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many, but QGIS is probably the most robust current offering. A few others:

- [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) -- high quality output, can render with Cairo and AGG for very nice results.
- [GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) has multiple ways of composing maps, including [wx.psmap](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Hardcopy_Map_Output_Utility)
- [MapWindow](http://www.mapwindow.org/) if you're on Windows
- [TileMill](http://tilemill.com/) is a web-based interface for generating maps using Mapnik as the backend

Lastly I'd mention [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), which isn't exclusively for maps, but its ability to parse PDFs and PS files means it can often be a useful post-processing tool for fine-grained control of maps generated in other software.

Most of the OS software uses GDAL/OGR for its actual data input/output, and currently there isn't any support for GeoPDF outputs unfortunately.

Comment: Though I was aware of `ps.map` in GRASS I didn't know about `wx.psmap`! Seems like it was added recently since the 6.4.2 version. Thanks for that since I primarily use GRASS.

Answer (score 3):

I cast a vote for [uDig](http://udig.refractions.net/). I find it comparable to qGIS and easy to use. It is built with Eclipse Rich Client technology which has added benefits:

- uDig can be used as a stand-alone application.
- uDig can be extended with RCP “plug-ins”.
- uDig can be used as a plug-in in an existing RCP application.

uDig uses the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org/) library for core GIS functionality like data reading, coordinate reprojection, rendering, etc. Developers will need some understanding of GeoTools to create more complex functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Today I came to know about [GMT](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/)(The Generic Mapping Tools).

> GMT is an open source collection of
>   ~60 tools for manipulating geographic
>   and Cartesian data sets (including
>   filtering, trend fitting, gridding,
>   projecting, etc.) and producing
>   Encapsulated PostScript File (EPS)
>   illustrations ranging from simple x-y
>   plots via contour maps to artificially
>   illuminated surfaces and 3-D
>   perspective views. GMT supports ~30
>   map projections and transformations
>   and comes with support data such as
>   GSHHS coastlines, rivers, and
>   political boundaries.

[Examples of GMT output](http://www.soest.hawaii.edu/gmt/gmt/gmt_examples.html)

Comment: It's of course a command line tool but I am impressed by its utility.

Comment: This sounds to me a lot like the ArcInfo 7.x "ArcPlot" module.  Are the concepts similar?

Comment: GMT is a quality toolset which deserves larger mindshare. It has been around a *long* time (1988) and has a large library of features, and (I believe) the single largest collection of projections in it's library.